# Abstract class vs relation between classes

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, inheritance, composition

Searching for simplest solution where a User can order an item.

If someone purchases an item he will have one address. Which then is the invoice and shipping address. But he could add another address if the invoice address is different from the shipping address.

I wrote some code with two Classes `Purchase` and `Address`. Where Purchase has a one-to-many relation with Address. So far so good and that all works fine.

But now, I might have a confusion.
I was thinking I could also create a `AbstractAddress` class. Where `Purchase` extends the `AbstractAddress` and `Address` also extends the `AbstractAddress`. Now if there is a `new Purchase` the Address will be part of Purchase and the relation (one-to-many) from Purchase to Address will only happen if the Purchase get's added one more Address.

Is that correct? Would that be better? Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not correct.

If you make `Purchase` extend `AbstractAddress`, you are saying that a `Purchase` is some kind of specialized `AbstractAddress`, which is not. It's like saying that a `Car` is a specialized `Windshield`.

The logical relationship between a `Purchase` and an `Address` is one of composition, not one of inheritance.

Just add two address members to Purchase.

**Pseudocode:**

```java
public class Purchase {

      private shippingAddress Address;
      private invoiceAddress Address;   

      public void setShippingAddress(Address address){
            set shippingAddress=address;
      }

      public void setInvoiceAddress(Address address){
            set invoiceAddress=address;
      }

      public Address getShippingAddress(Address address){
            return shippingAddress;
      }

      public Address getInvoiceAddress(){
            return invoiceAddress;
      }

}
```

---

Comment: Maybe its a good idea to let both addresses point to the same address instance, initially? Preferably passed to the constructor. Then you can just get the shipping address without having to know if it is or isnt the same address as the invoice address.